# Change data in tableView swift

Tags: swift, view, uikit, tableview

I am working on a project to change the array that is being displayed by a tableview when the segment value is changed. What is the easiest way to accomplish this? Thanks!

```
  @IBAction func segmentValueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender == testSwitcher {
            if testSwitcher.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                print("Hello World")
            }
            else if testSwitcher.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
                print("Data Update")
                newArray = []
                stateElections.data = newArray
                stateElections.reloadData()
     }
```

Comment: so what is the issue with ur methoda?

Comment: I cant change the data in stateElections to reflect the new data in the array

Comment: stateElections is a model or tableview's variable name? If its tableview's variable name , tableview dont have a property name data ; if its model , u are not reloading tableview?

Comment: just change your model data and then call tableView.reloadData()

Comment: It is not the model name it's the tableView name that code was just an examole of what I'm looking to do. I am not sure in my code which list edits the tablview is there a way to tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement something like below

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        
        switch(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
        {
        case 0:
            myCell.textLabel!.text = arrayList1[indexPath.row]
            break
        case 1:
            myCell.textLabel!.text = arrayList2[indexPath.row]
            break
            
        case 2:
            myCell.textLabel!.text = arrayList3[indexPath.row]
            break
            
        default:
            break
            
        }


        return myCell
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func segmentedControlActionChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, take care that your tableView is not set up as a static table in the storyboard, because those will never update.

You MUST setup a data source object (an object that adopts the UITableViewDataSource protocol) to have a dynamic table in UIKit.

UITableView uses a delegation pattern to dynamically provide the data, see the Apple docs for UITableViewDataSource, specifically https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views/filling_a_table_with_data

So, after you have updated your data model, you simply trigger the reload of the cells on your tableView by calling reloadData() on the tableView, which then asks the tableViewDataSource for data.

Additional note:

This all is way easier and pretty straightforward in SwiftUI, so if you have the option in your project to wrap SwiftUI code for the use in your UIKit project, I would consider that as an alternative.